# Read data from firestore is undefined

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to read data from firestore document specific vield but it is turn undefined. i dont know why, this is my code:

```
const [alluser, setAllUser] = useState([])
console.log(alluser.fullname)

useEffect(() => {
   db.collection('users').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const listUser = []
      querySnapshot.forEach((user) => {
          listUser.push(user.data())
      })
      setAllUser(listUser)
   })
}, [])
```

in my console log say "undefined". I don't know what's wrong... any suggestion?? please help

Comment: Please put `console.log(user.data())` before `listUser.push(user.data())`

Comment: try logging `listUser` right before `setAllUser(listUser)`

Comment: `alluser` is an array and not an object with `fullname` property.

Comment: i logged already, i still got the doc, but it can't show the specific field value...

Comment: Where in the UI are you trying to show the value? Can you share the component as well ?